# Eclipse keeps on crashing while coding

Tags: eclipse, crash

Please, could anyone help me? I have tried searching for an answer on google many times already but to no avail.

My problem is Eclipse keeps on crashing when I am writing code (in Java). When it crashes, it doesn't tell me what error has occurred, it just says it has stopped working. (It just leaves me like that.. poof!) I'm always restarting Eclipse, typing some code and then it crashes again, repeat process.

I would like to know,

1. How do I find what's wrong?
2. (If objective no.1 has been fulfilled) How do I correct it?

If anyone of you would help me out, thank you very much.

Comment: What OS are you using? Is it a recent behaviour? Has it ever worked fine? Have you tried to uninstall it and reinstall it?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 (32-bit). Yes, it was just fine when I was using it during the March until August time period. I started using Eclipse again in October and this problem started happening. I got rid of Juno and got Kepler, but the same thing is happening. @HAL90000

Comment: Please post what you are getting in the "Error" view.  Press `Ctrl + 3`, and type `Error` to get the `Error` view.

Comment: I have the same problem under Linux (Opensuse 13.1) with eclipse keppler 8.2.1. The error log shows nothing... several warnings for keybinding conflicts, but those date from other moments than the crash...

Comment: @ChrisMaes I didn't have any errors. I figured my laptop could be infected. So I got it formatted and hey, Eclipse ran nicely then. Crashes no more.